# three.js horizontal PlaneGeometry at x=0 y=0 z=0

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Hi I have this code that draws the image below

```
window.onload = function()
{
    // init renderer
    var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    canvas_width=side; canvas_height=side;
    renderer.setSize(canvas_width,canvas_height);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // init scene and camera
    var scene=new THREE.Scene();
    var camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90,canvas_width/canvas_height,1,100);
    camera.position.y=5;
    camera.position.z=25;

    var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'arrow.png' );
    var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25,25),img);
    mesh.overdraw = true;
    scene.add(mesh);

    // a light
    var light=new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff,0x000000,1.5);
    light.position.set(1,1,1);
    scene.add(light);

    // render
    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene,camera);        
    })
}
```

[image]

but I want to draw the PlaneGeometry horizontally instead of vertically, not rotating it with `mesh.rotation.x=THREE.Math.degToRad(-90);`, to get this at x=0 y=0 z=0:
[image]

so that with

```
mesh.rotation.x=THREE.Math.degToRad(-90);
```

the arrow will pointing down

and with:

```
mesh.rotation.x=THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
```

the arrow will pointing up

can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, rotating the geometry with `.rotateX()`:

```js
// init renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
canvas_width = window.innerWidth;
canvas_height = window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize(canvas_width, canvas_height);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// init scene and camera
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, canvas_width / canvas_height, 1, 100);
camera.position.y = 5;
camera.position.z = 25;

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg');
var img = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

// mesh
geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25, 25);
geom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5); // this is how you can do it
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, img);
mesh.overdraw = true;
scene.add(mesh);

// a light
var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 1.5);
light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add(light);

// render
requestAnimationFrame(function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok but if I rotate it with `mesh.rotation.x=THREE.Math.degToRad(-45);` I can't see it, as if the other side is black

Comment: I've updated the snippet. Added `side: THREE.DoubleSide` to the material.

Comment: I tried using `THREE.BoxGeometry( 25,25,1)` instead of `THREE.PlaneGeometry(25,25)` to give a thickness to the plane, but I'd like to have it only on the shape of the transparent png image, the arrow in my case, instead  of on the entire 25x25 square. is it possible?

Comment: @Miky You can create another question with detailed description and pictures of the desired result :) But so far, what I can understand from your comment, is that you're looking for something like `THREE.Shape()` and `THREE.ShapeGeometry()`/`THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry()`. Have a look at this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shapes#webgl_geometry_shapes)